# Register page - asp.net (Add to db)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've building a project with asp.net. 
I have a table in the db that calls - Customers.

Customers (CustomerID, ,Mail, Password, firstName, lastName , address)

The original registaration page includes only fields for mail, password, confirm password.

**I want to add new fields in the regestaration page that will show up in the register page and the data that the users are put in will be saved in Customers table.**

I've changed the register page according to this tutorial -

https://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/

And now the new fields are shown in the register page.

Ive got this error - "the model backing the database context has changed since the database was created"

I want to connect between the new fields that Ive added to the db (Customers table).

How can I do that?

And another question - If I am not doing any changes and a user is registered to my web site - where this data is saved?

TNX!

Comment: Why did four people upvote this? Please read [ask] and share your research. The error tells you exactly what you need to do: sync your database and your DbContext, for example through migrations.